# How to dynamically link your nim-application against musl?

Tags: compilation, dynamic-linking, nim-lang, musl

I've written a web-server in nim using the prologue framework. I would like to deploy that application using an alpine-docker-container.
As far as I'm aware, compiling means you dynamically link against your system libraries for whatever you need, that system library on any normal distro being `glibc`.
On alpine however you do not use `glibc`, you use `musl`, so dynamically linking against `glibc` means my application will expect glibc functions with `glibc` names that do not exist since there are only `musl` functions.

The big question that arises out of this for me as a python developer that jumped onto nim and knows very little about compilers:
How do I compile, so that I link dynamically against `musl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folks from nim discord's brought me to the answer. It consists of passing flags to the nim-compiler to swap out the compiler nim normally uses for its generated C-code, in order to use `musl-gcc`. This can be done by using the `--gcc.exe:"musl-gcc"` and `--gcc.linkerexe:"musl-gcc"` flags.

Here an example for Linux:

###### 1. install musl to get access to musl-gcc

- [download](https://www.musl-libc.org/download.html) the tar file from the official musl page
- Unpack the tar file somewhere
- Run bash configure in the unpacked directory. WARNING: Make sure that you do NOT install musl with `--prefix` being `/usr/local`, as that may adversely affect your system. Use somewhere else where it is unlikely to override files, e.g. `/usr/local/musl`. This path will further be referred to as `<MUSL_INSTALL_PATH>`
- Run `make && make install` in the unpacked directory
- Add `<MUSL_INSTALL_PATH>` to your `PATH` environment variable
- Validate whether you set everything up correctly by opening a new terminal and seeing whether you have access to the musl-gcc command

###### 2. Compile with musl

- Create a compile command with `--gcc.exe:"musl-gcc"` to swap out gcc with musl-gcc and `--gcc.linkerexe:"musl-gcc"` to swap out the default linker with musl-gcc as well. An example can look like this:

```bash
nim c \
--gcc.exe:"musl-gcc" \
--gcc.linkerexe:"musl-gcc" \
--define:release \
--threads:on \
--mm:orc \
--deepcopy:on \
--define:lto \
--outdir:"." \
<PATH_TO_YOUR_MAIN_PROJECT_FILE>.nim
```

- run the command

This should generate a binary that is dynamically linked against musl and thus can run within an alpine docker container.